# Webpack doesn't recognize Bluebird Promise

Tags: typescript, promise, bluebird, webpack-2, typescript-typings

Visual Studio intellisense recognizes correctly that the Promise is from Bluebird, however it seems like webpack gets confused and when i debug the main bundle in the browser I see that the Promise is not the 'bluebird' Promise.

I am using the Asp.net core template for reactJS. I have: 
"webpack": "2.5.1",
"bluebird": "3.5.1",
"@types/bluebird": "2.0.33"

This is my ts.config:

```
{ 
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./ClientApp",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    //"strict": true,
    "lib": [ "dom", "es5", "es2015.iterable", "scripthost", "es2015.promise" ],
    "types": [ "webpack-env" ],
    "experimentalDecorators": true
 },
  "exclude": [
      "bin",
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

How can I configure webpack to always use the 'bluebird' Promise?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your webpack config

```
global.Promise = require('bluebird')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this didn't help.